Spring Kafka - CommonErrorHandler ignored on DeserializationException
I'd need some clarification from Spring Kafka connoisseurs onto the reasoning behind the following error handling & behaviour.
My intention was to have an ExponentionalBackOff exposed as the default CommonErrorHandler and catch essentially all possible exceptions. If an error occurs, some monitoring/alerting kicks in and I would be fixing whatever goes wrong. No DLQ configured for now, we would be blocking the queue.
@Bean
CommonErrorHandler commonErrorHandler() {
    var exponentialBackOff = new ExponentialBackOff();
    exponentialBackOff.setMaxInterval(Duration.ofHours(1).toMillis());
    return new DefaultErrorHandler(exponentialBackOff);
}

The default consumption property based configuration:
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DelegatingByTopicDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.kafka.key.serialization.bytopic.default=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.kafka.key.serialization.bytopic.config=\
    topic.order.archive-invoice-event:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer

Listener looks like as follow:
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic.order.archive-invoice-event")
void onArchiveInvoice(ArchiveInvoiceEvent event) {
    invoiceService.archiveInvoice(event.getOrderId());
}

If an exception occurs at runtime during the consumption of an event, everything is fine, meaning the commonErrorHandler takes over as expected.
However, I ran into an issue whereby the producer decided to change the type of the serialized key from Integer to String.
At runtime I got the following log:
Backoff FixedBackOff{interval=0, currentAttempts=1, maxAttempts=0} exhausted for topic.order.archive-invoice-event-1@489253

And stacktrace
o.a.k.c.e.SerializationException: Size of data received by IntegerDeserializer is not 4
    at o.a.k.c.s.IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(IntegerDeserializer.java:30)
    at o.a.k.c.s.IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(IntegerDeserializer.java:24)
    at o.a.k.c.s.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:62)
    at o.s.k.s.s.DelegatingByTopicDeserializer.deserialize(DelegatingByTopicDeserializer.java:78)
    at o.s.k.s.s.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:215)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: o.s.k.s.s.DeserializationException: failed to deserialize
    at o.s.k.s.s.SerializationUtils.deserializationException(SerializationUtils.java:158)
    at o.s.k.s.s.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:218)
    at o.a.k.c.s.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73)
    at o.a.k.c.c.i.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:319)

I retraced the exception and the only place where a FixedBackOff policy is used is in
FailedRecordProcessor (used by AbstractMessageListenerContainer).
This FailedRecordProcessor applies some bits of magic and overules the commonErrorHandling in case of classified exceptions (such as DeserializationException).
Two questions here:

Why? Is that really intended or have I misconfigured anything?
Any way for capturing Deserialization Exceptions (key / value)? Based on the this baeldung article I was led to believe it was the right approach and the Spring documentation is not clear enough to me

Thank you for your enlightenment
Dependencies:

spring-boot: 3.3.5
spring-kafka: 3.2.4



Why? Is that really intended or have I misconfigured anything?

As mentioned by @artem the documentation does mention some fatal exceptions which bypass the custom error handling logic.
DeserializationException
MessageConversionException
ConversionException
MethodArgumentResolutionException
NoSuchMethodException
ClassCastException

Therefore, for anyone willing to apply the same error strategy independently of the origin of the error, the default provided by Spring can be overridden as follow:
@Bean
CommonErrorHandler commonErrorHandler() {

    var exponentialBackOff = new ExponentialBackOff();
    exponentialBackOff.setMaxInterval(Duration.ofHours(1).toMillis());

    var handler = new DefaultErrorHandler(exponentialBackOff);

    // unified error handling
    handler.setClassifications(Map.of(), true);

    return handler;
}


Not clear what is the question.
See a ExceptionClassifier, which is a super class of the DefaultErrorHandler:
/**
 * Remove an exception type from the configured list. By default, the following
 * exceptions will not be retried:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link DeserializationException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MessageConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MethodArgumentResolutionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link NoSuchMethodException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ClassCastException}</li>
 * </ul>
 * All others will be retried, unless {@link #defaultFalse()} has been called.
 * @param exceptionType the exception type.
 * @return the classification of the exception if removal was successful;
 * null otherwise.
 * @since 2.8.4
 * @see #addNotRetryableExceptions(Class...)
 * @see #setClassifications(Map, boolean)
 */
@Nullable
public Boolean removeClassification(Class<? extends Exception> exceptionType) {

So, those exceptions are fatal by default and they do not go to the mentioned backoff. That is also mentioned in the doc.
That article talks about a custom CommonErrorHandler  where they provide a custom logic into a handle() implementation to deal with that RecordDeserializationException.

If someone is looking for the mentioned documentation, here it is: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/annotation-error-handling.html#default-eh

Thanks for your quicky reply @artem. The documentation does specify the fatal exceptions indeed, which I didn't see straight away and therefore I missed the setClassifications as well. I will make a proper answer with the working code.
